# gtkmm drag and drop - How to pass a message from drag source to drop destination on drag motion event?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtkmm

I would like a gtkmm drag and drop destination to make decisions based on data from the source before the drop occurs. Is it possible to request the data from the "drag motion" callback? I see hints of it in the documentation but no clear example of how.

[The gtkmm 3.24 documentation for signal_drag_data_received](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.24/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#aa9874ac0ca5550679a0322d2c5b5fba2) says

> The signal_drag_data_received() signal is emitted on the drop site when the dragged data has been received. If the data was received in order to determine whether the drop will be accepted, the handler is expected to call gdk_drag_status() and not finish the drag.

It seems to hint that the data can be requested before the drop. But I am not sure if it is possible or how to do it. The following is a working example of a drag and drop with the  `signal_drag_data_get`, `signal_drag_data_received`, and `signal_drag_motion` signals connected.

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include "test_window.h"

int
main (int    argc,
        char **argv)
{
    int result = 0;
    argc = 1;
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.test_app");
    app->set_flags(Gio::APPLICATION_NON_UNIQUE);
    test_window test_window_i;
    result = app->run(test_window_i);

    return result;
}
```

test_window.h

```cpp
#ifndef SRC_TEST_WINDOW_H_
#define SRC_TEST_WINDOW_H_
#include <gtkmm.h>

class test_window: public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    test_window();

    void source_get_data(
                const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::DragContext>& context,
                Gtk::SelectionData& selection_data,
                guint info,
                guint time);

    void destination_received_data(
                        const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::DragContext>& context,
                        int x,
                        int y,
                        const Gtk::SelectionData & selection_data,
                        guint info,
                        guint time);

    bool destination_drag_motion_event(
                    const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::DragContext>& context,
                    int x,
                    int y,
                    guint time);

private:
    Gtk::Box m_box;
    Gtk::Button m_source;
    Gtk::Button m_destination;    
};
#endif
```

test_window.cpp

```cpp
#include "test_window.h"
#include <iostream>

test_window::test_window()
{
    show_all();

    set_border_width(1);

    set_type_hint(Gdk::WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_NORMAL);
    resize(800, 800);
    add(m_box);

    m_box.set_orientation(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
    m_box.pack_start(m_source, true,  false);
    m_box.pack_start(m_destination, true,  false);

    m_source.set_label("source");
    m_destination.set_label("destination");

    std::vector<Gtk::TargetEntry> drag_targets = {
                                        Gtk::TargetEntry("STRING"),
                                        Gtk::TargetEntry("text/plain")};

    m_source.drag_source_set(drag_targets);
    m_destination.drag_dest_set(drag_targets);

    m_source.signal_drag_data_get().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &test_window::source_get_data));
    m_destination.signal_drag_data_received().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &test_window::destination_received_data));
    m_destination.signal_drag_motion ().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &test_window::destination_drag_motion_event));

    show_all();
}

void test_window::source_get_data(
                            const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::DragContext>& context,
                            Gtk::SelectionData& selection_data,
                            guint info,
                            guint time)
{
    std::string source_message = "Hello from source.";

    selection_data.set(
                    selection_data.get_target(),
                    8 /* 8 bits format */,
                    (const guchar*)source_message.c_str(),
                    source_message.size());
}

void test_window::destination_received_data(
                            const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::DragContext>& context,
                            int x,
                            int y,
                            const Gtk::SelectionData & selection_data,
                            guint info,
                            guint time)
{
    if ((selection_data.get_length() >= 0) && (selection_data.get_format() == 8))
    {
        std::string message = selection_data.get_data_as_string();
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
    }

    context->drag_finish(false, false, time);
}

bool test_window::destination_drag_motion_event(
                                const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::DragContext>& context,
                                int x,
                                int y,
                                guint time)
{
    std::cout << "Destination drag motion event." << std::endl;    
    return true;
}
```

Makefile

```
EXECUTABLE=test_app
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -g 

CC=g++
# 
SOURCES= src/main.cpp src/test_window.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
  $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs` 

.cpp.o:
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags` 

clean:
  rm -rf src/*.o  $(EXECUTABLE)
```